# Issues with redirecting output of a command to a file

Tags: shell, io-redirection

I have a pretty weird issue. Might be a simple one. Maybe I am missing something.

I have a command:

```
# dpnctl status all
```

The output of this is:

```
> Identity added: /home/dpn/.ssh/dpnid (/home/dpn/.ssh/dpnid) dpnctl:
> INFO: gsan status: up dpnctl: INFO: MCS status: up. dpnctl: INFO: emt
> status: up. dpnctl: INFO: Backup scheduler status: up. dpnctl: INFO:
> axionfs status: down. dpnctl: INFO: Maintenance windows scheduler
> status: enabled. dpnctl: INFO: Unattended startup status: enabled.
```

I tried:

```
dpnctl status all > /output.txt
dpnctl status all >> /output.txt
```

And both of these return the file as empty. The command does not populate all the status at once. It will output each service status with ~1 second delay. This is why I used >> rather than a regular re-direct >

Any idea what's causing this? 
Thanks.

Comment: Could be outputting to stderr, so try 2> instead of >

Comment: Yep. It indeed was. &> did it

Answer (score 1):

Never mind. I figured it out:

```
dpnctl status &> /output.txt
```